# Mapbox blank screen in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-ndk, mapbox

I'm trying to make a map application in android studio using Mapbox and it used to work but now only displays a blank screen.

I have been fiddling with it trying to make it work for ages, to no avail. I also have a 'Compativle side by side NDK version was not found. Default is 20.0.5594570' error/warning I do not understand either. Any help will be much appreciated and TIA.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private MapView mapView;
private MapboxMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.access_token));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
    map = mapboxMap;
    mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.OUTDOORS);

    mapboxMap.setCameraPosition(
            new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(53.472, -2.239))
                .zoom(8.0)
                .build());

    mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(53.472, -2.239))
            .title("John Dalton"));
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mapView.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mapView.onResume();
}
```

The rest of the code is just onStop() functions etc.

build.gradle (:app):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.stationmapper"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    //Mapbox dependencies
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.0.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v9:0.8.0'
}
```

I think this is enough code to scope and fix the problem but if anything else is needed, I will edit and provide it.

Answer (score 2):

Your activity implements `OnMapReadyCallback`, but you're missing `mapView.getMapAsync(this)` after `mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`.

```
@Override public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
  map = mapboxMap;
  mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.OUTDOORS, new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
    @Override public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {

    // Map is set up and the style has loaded. Now you can add data or make other map adjustments.

    }
  });
}
```

Then, add the marker in the `onStyleLoaded()` callback area.

Rather than using the deprecated addMarker(), consider using Mapbox's Annotation Plugin https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/overview/annotation or `SymbolLayer`s and sources https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/annotations/#source-and-layer

Answer (score 0):

Android Gradle Plugin 3.6+ has an internally embedded NDK version to use if you do NOT call out which version to use. The **[SHORT ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61157024/compatible-side-by-side-ndk-version-was-not-found-default-is-20-0-5594570/61510602#61510602)** is to use `android.ndkVersion` in your module's build.gradle file.

Even your app does not directly use NDK, you might still experience the error as mapbox needs NDK to build/has native libs, refer to [the filed issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154275600).